# One Access point two SSIDs = seperate Networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I use an UniFi UAP access point and a non-wifi router.

Everything in my home is hooked up to the same SSID on the AP. Only wired clients to the router are my NAS, Sonos Bridge and surveillance DVR.

I'd like to provide the kids friends internet access, whitout giving them the wifi code to the primary SSID and without giving the access to NAS files etc.

The AP provides a Guest Network option, but it requires a client to be running on my PC to work. Most often the PC is off, so this is not an option.

Question 1; If I create an other SSID on the AP (with a different security code) will these SSID's be separated? I.e. will the act as two separated networks?

Question 2; In my setup, can I provide the kids internet access only, and no access to NAS etc.

kind regards Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, they appear as separate network interfaces to your AP’s operating system.
2. Theoretically, yes. However, you’d need to separate the two networks on the AP/router connection, using VLANs. I doubt your router supports this. Your AP probably does.

Basically, what you want is a guest WiFi network. Guests can connect to the internet, but not your wired network. Many WiFi routers offer this option. If the AP is a separate device, it’s not that easy. Perhaps getting a new router would be a more desirable solution.